# Only get the first tag content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want only to get the "22" out of the code...

```
<div class="left">
<a class="count-link" href="http://url1.com">
<span>22</span>
users
</a>
<a class="count-link" href="http://url2.com">
<span>10</span>
users
</a>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
var text = $('.count-link span').text()
alert(text);
```

but this will return 2210

How can I get only the 22 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `:first()` selector as shown :

```
var text = $('.count-link span:first').text()
```

Comment: Wow so many right answers right away.. thank you! I can only accept one, so I will take the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
var text = $('.count-link span').first().text()
```

Comment: Wow so many right answers right away.. thank you! I can only accept one, so I will take the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $($('.count-link span')[0]).text()
alert(text);
```

Comment: `$('.count-link span')[0]` will return a dom element reference so `.tex()` will throw anerror

Comment: Wow so many right answers right away.. thank you! I can only accept one, so I will take the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:first` selector

```js
var text = $('.count-link:first span').text()
alert(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <a class="count-link" href="http://url1.com">
    <span>22</span>
    users
  </a>
  <a class="count-link" href="http://url2.com">
    <span>10</span>
    users
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow so many right answers right away.. thank you! I can only accept one, so I will take the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var text = $('.left span:first').text();
alert(text);
```

Comment: Wow so many right answers right away.. thank you! I can only accept one, so I will take the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the `eq()` filter in jquery

```
var text = $("span").eq(0).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var text = $('.count-link span:first').text()
alert(text);
```

or

```
var text = $('.left span:eq(0)').text()
alert(text);
```